# Principled Shader - blue subsurface color for thin parts

Tags: rendering, materials

I am traying to render a character in blender. I am using Principled BSDF.
As a subsurface emthod I am using Random walk, since it gives more realistic results. Whole face is fine except eyelids. They become blue. I guess it is due to thin geometry. Any Ideas How to solve the problem?

[image]

--Edited--

Here is shader graph:
[image]

As Base color I use orangish colored texture. SubsurfaceFactor is a gray scale map. I used original Subsurface Radius values (1.0, 0.2, 0.1) multiplied by black color to steer the radius easily.

I get this thin geometry using boolean modifier. I subtracted eye shape from teh face shape to prevent flesh appearing in cornea.

Another problem are those strange speckles in shaded area? Does anybody know what cause them? I had same problem when I worked with Arnold Render, so probably something's wrong with my setup.

[image]

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about your shader setup and maybe show the nodetree? What's your subsurf radius vector?

Comment: I am experimenting the same thing (the blue color on thin surface). I think it happens when the thickness is under the blue color radius (or the color -red green or blue- which has the min radius). Maybe we could play with inverted ao to reduce the sss scale on these thin surface (Not tried yet)

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents tweak to avoid blue patch on thin surface:
[image]

I adjusted the distance of the ambiance occlusion to be small enough to be near to zero on thin surfaces.
I disabled "only local" to prevent collisions with external objects to also add blue color around the collision surface.

Here is how my ao values look like:

[image]

As a result, from this: [image]

... to no more makeup: [image]