# Render issue: How to get the correct skin color

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, subsurface-scattering

I recently made a human head in blender. I try to render a very soft and a transparent texture of skin .When I try to increase the subsurface value, the skin will feel as transparent as I want, but at the same time the corners of the mouth and the side ears will appear green. I've tried increasing the subsurface‘s R value and lower the G and B values, but the results are not very good. Can anyone tell me how I can get rid of this green color while maintaining the existing skin translucency?

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: This is kind of a common limitation of Subsurface Scattering - areas that would have high "ambient occlusion" (and sometimes very thin areas), bleed negative values because the SSS occluders have an infinite limit. Have a look at _this question/answer_ -https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108457/principled-shader-blue-subsurface-color-for-thin-parts - for a trick to bring the limit down closer to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the *Subsurface Method* to *Christensen-Burley* instead of the default *Random Walk*. This will look different in general, but it gets rid of the green areas and maybe you have to adjust the other values a bit as well. It's all a matter of tweaking until it looks okay.

[image: subsurface settings]

[image: subsurface comparison]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering . I've tried it before. It can reduce the green area but as you said it changes all. The skin looks less transparent. But as there is no other way. I think I'll try to adjust the other values as you suggest  to make it more transparent.